# Java Stream LambdaExp ForEach_

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, foreach, java-stream

I can't understand why it doesn't work, print without `+"a"`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> stringi = new ArrayList<>();
    String a = "gg";
    String a2 = "hf";
    String a3 = "wp";
    stringi.add(a);
    stringi.add(a2);
    stringi.add(a3);
    stringi.stream().forEach((x) -> x.concat("str"));
    stringi.forEach((s) -> {
        System.out.println(s);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like you think, in your code the concat is useless, because you don't stock the result of concatenation in any Object.

To get the correct result, you can replace the first forEach with a map, then a for each after for example :

```
stringi.stream()
        .map(x -> x.concat("str"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or you can collect the result in a List then print each element :

```
List<String> result = stringi.stream()
        .map(x -> x.concat("str"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want to change the initial List, then :

```
stringi = stringi.stream()
        .map(x -> x.concat("str"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ty, it`s work, but my List is doesn`t change.

Comment: second, it what I want, tnx you man.

Comment: @ArsenDmitriiev If you want to change the initial list, then `stringi = stringi.stream()
        .map(x -> x.concat("str"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: rly tnx, I wasted 2 hours, read about streams, etc. You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work as Srings in JAVA are immutable. So when `x.concat("str")` executes, it basically creates a new string in the memory with content as `ggstr` for the first string and so on. But the list `stringi` still has the reference of the string `gg` and so on.